# React Native change button opacity conditionally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I created a floating action button and I want to change the opacity when i reach the end of my `ScrollView`. So I use:

```
<TouchableOpacity
  activeOpacity={0.5}
  onPress={() => {
    this.scrollView.scrollToEnd({ animated: true });
    this.setState({ buttonIsRight: false });
  }}
  style={[
    styles.rightFAB,
    this.state.buttonIsRight ? { opacity: 1 } : { opacity: 0 }
  ]}
>
  <Image
    source={require("../icons/plus.png")}
    style={{
      resizeMode: "center",
      aspectRatio: 1 / 1,
      tintColor: "#888888"
    }}
  />
</TouchableOpacity>;
```

but there is no change in `opacity` at all! I set `onPress` to scroll to end and change a state so i can change the opacity based on that state.

Any idea?

> Thanks in advance!

Comment: create an opacity constant and then use it? const opacity = condition ? 0.5 : 0.8;   activeOpacity={opacity}

Comment: Why i can't use state?

Comment: u can do with that as well.

Comment: 1st of all check that this.state.buttonIsRight value is for else condition. this.state.buttonIsRight value should be null, false or undefined. may be condition is not working
2nd thing is check opacity by apply  without condition.  is it  working or not 
than let me know

Comment: Not working and condition is ok

Comment: `style={[ styles.rightFAB,{opacity:condition ? 0.5 : 0.7}]}` this should work. Hoping that your `styles.rightFAB` is stylesheet obj

Comment: still not working!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> There is already an issue with TouchableOpacity when changing the
>   opacity like the way you want to.

Check this issue page, https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17105

The simple solution till its fixed in the react-native core is to wrap the children components of TouchableOpacity in a View and apply the opacity logic to that View.

Simple example,

```
class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    opacity: 1
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          {/* Apply opacity logic to the wrapper View */} 
          <View 
            style={{
              backgroundColor: 'grey', 
              opacity: this.state.opacity
            }} 
          >
            <Text>My Button</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{backgroundColor: 'orange'}}
          onPress={() => this.setState({opacity: !!this.state.opacity? 0 : 1}) }
        >
          <Text>Change opacity</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
});
```

A working example in snack.expo: https://snack.expo.io/r1vMfVg8m

> Try my work around on both iOS and Android. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

May you can achieve this by defining style inline rather than using  styles.rightFAB.

if  styles.rightFAB =  **{ alignItems: 'center', padding: 10 }** then define them in TouchableOpacity style.

```
<TouchableOpacity
  style={{
   alignItems: 'center', 
   padding: 10,
   opacity: this.state.buttonIsRight ?  1: 0 
  }}
 >
```

Answer (score 1):

In element using

```
    <View>
      <OnPlay />
    </View>
```

In function using

```
  function OnPlay() {
     const [iconPlay, setIconPlay] = useState(false);
     const [opacity, setOpacity] = useState(0);
     const show = <Image source={require('../assets/images/play-circle-outline.svg')} style={styles.welcomeImage} />;
     const hide = <Image source={require('../assets/images/pause-circle-outline.svg')} style={styles.welcomeImage} />;
         function onPressButton() {
           setIconPlay(!iconPlay);
           let val = !iconPlay == false ? 1 : 0;
           setOpacity(val);
         }
  return (
    <RectButton onPress={onPressButton} activeOpacity={opacity}  >
      {iconPlay ? show : hide}
    </RectButton>
  )
}
```

Hope this help.